# How to kill a Windows running exe with Python

Tags: python, kill-process, taskmanager

How to End task this exe file in background processes:

[image]

my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
import win32com.client

wmi=win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')

for p in wmi.InstancesOf('win32_process'):    
    # print(p.Name)
    if p.Name == 'boltzmann.exe':
        print("Ok")
```

Comment: Can you try `p.Terminate()`?

Comment: p.terminate() is not working

Comment: "is not working" ... Does it raise an error (if so what?) or does it just NOT stop the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Code I used process chrome.exe as an example (replace it with boltzmann.exe):

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
import win32com.client
import signal


wmi=win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')


def getpid(process_name):
    import os
    return [item.split()[1] for item in os.popen('tasklist').read().splitlines()[4:] if process_name in item.split()]


for p in wmi.InstancesOf('win32_process'):
    if p.Name == 'chrome.exe':
        process_id = getpid('chrome.exe')
        if len(process_id) > 1:
            for x in process_id:
                pid = int(x)
                os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

        else:
            pid = int("".join(getpid('chrome.exe')))
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

I tried my best to make this all using inbuilt libraries so that you won't have to import lot of stuff

**SOME NOTES:**

1. The process name is case sensitive
2. If the Process is running on higher priority then process won't terminate, and a access denied error will appear